# Firebase services not working in another device when app is cloned from bitbucket

Tags: firebase, kotlin, bitbucket, android-jetpack-compose

I've created a Jetpack Compose app in Android Studio and I'm using Firebase services (Auth and Firestore). Everything works fine. I can access and create registers, but is a team project, so I uploaded all the project to Bitbucket, and my team cloned the repo.
When my team tried to login with the same user/password, the app keeps waiting and don't even create an error message in "Log" or "Run" window.

We already tried by adding the next line in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also, we already sync **build.gradle** and check for versions of implementations (and that couldn't be the problem because is a cloned repo, so everything remains the same).

As a detail that I think it could be affecting this: the package name in manifest keeps the same. Is this wrong?

When run the app, this seems to be working fine, even throw this messages.

```
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
```

And this is what I get from trying to do an auth operation

```
D/TrafficStats: tagSocket(98) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
```

If you have experienced this problem, I would appreciate all the help I can get, thank you so much.

Comment: Firebase Auth requires same `SHA-1 fingerprint`. Are you both using the same release signing key?

Answer (score 0):

An error occurred in the transfer-and-conversion process, most likely. You wrote code, you compiled it, it ran well. Then, you transferred it to a repo, so if the transfer process was faulty (some file(s) didn't go to the repo / something underwent a partial transfer), it would break right away even if you run it on your own device by downloading from there. Now, if the transfer wasn't faulty, their conversion to an APK could be.

#### Debugging

To confirm where the problem lies, upload the code to the same bucket as you mention, then download the code again and compile in a fresh project. If it doesn't compile, transfer is faulty (or none of you know how to compile). If it compiles and runs as expected, their conversion/compilation is at fault and you've got nothing to worry about, except the fact that you have a team of useless drunks.

#### Solution

Should be obvious, if they can't make the end-product by themselves (those useless drunks), give it to them on a platter.

In Studio, go to "Build > Generate APK(s)". A confirmation dialog will have the link to the generated file once it's done. Share the apk directly with your "team" and see if it works. No need to see, it *will* work. Why do you have all the code if you are in a "team". Is it one of those teams where a single person does everything?

Comment: I still didn't find the real issue because the Log is not showing any kind of error, but I saw something interesting: 

The app has stopped working in my laptop after updating Android Studio, gradle assistant and the emulator. The curious thing is that this only happens when using the emulator, if we use a physical device (even my partners with their cloned repo), the application works fine and there's no delay in the response, while in the emulator is not receiving any result, error or anything. 

My conclusion is that the update of the emulator has some troubles with Firebase.